# is there an excel formula to find max item in a pivot table

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

i have a pivot table with:

1. Teams as the Row Label
2. Regions as the Column Label

and count of Application data

i want to have a column that displays the Region with the highest count for each Team.

So if my table looks like this:

Team | US | Europe | Asia
Team A   3  2  1
Team B   1  2  3
Team C   1  1  3
Team D   1  2  3

for Team A it would return US.  For Team D it would return Asia
is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ideas:

- use conditional formating on the pivot table
- try something along a custom maxif function (see this [blogpost](http://www.dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2004/06/29/maxif-minif-functions/)) on the pivot 
  datasource

EDIT:
If you copy the pivot table to a normal sheet, you could use the `index` twice to get what you want. Assuming your example data resides in A1:D5, you could put in E2 for instance

```
=INDEX(B$1:D$1,INDEX(B2:D2,MAX(B2:D2)))
```

If you have a row with two maximum values, the first max column will be returned.

[Google refine](http://code.google.com/p/google-refine/) appears to be a free tool very well suited for this kind of data manipulation.

Comment: what if i copy the pivot table to a regular "table" in excel.  is there anyway to get that formula then ??

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to copy the PT to a 'regular' table:

```
=INDEX($C$3:EG$3,,MATCH(MAX(C4:E4),C4:E4,0))
```

in H4 in the example and copied down to suit may to serve.

[image: SO4779080 example]

However, this does only pick the first instance of a maximum value that is repeated within a row (example adapted to show this) whereas Conditional Formatting does not have this possible drawback when applied to =C4:E7 with a rule such as:

```
=C4=MAX($C4:$E4)
```