# Excel formula to find reference to top row

Tags: excel-formula

I have a list of our top 5 customers by sales dollars. I would like to be able to dynamically find the top item purchased by those customers. I have all of our sales data in a pivot table. The first column lists all of our customer names, the first row lists our items. The values are the sum of quantity sold per customer. For example:

```
Customer | ItemA | ItemB | ItemC | ItemD
CustomerA    2       4       3       5
CustomerB    3       6       9       1
CustomerC    5       2       7       3
CustomerD    4       5       1       4
```

Let's say our top 2 customers by sales dollars are CustomerA and CustomerC. So the results should be:

```
CustomerA ItemD
CustomerC ItemC
```

There is a similar thread here: [is there an excel formula to find max item in a pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779080/is-there-an-excel-formula-to-find-max-item-in-a-pivot-table), but the double index formula solution limits the values (quantities) to be equal to or less than the number of columns in your table.

Answer (score 0):

Though with limited testing, this seems to work if `Customer` in your PT is in E3 and the formula is placed somewhere convenient in Row4 and copied down to suit:

> =IF(E4="A",MAX(GETPIVOTDATA("Val",$E$2,"Customer","A","Item","a"),GETPIVOTDATA("Val",$E$2,"Customer","A","Item","b"),GETPIVOTDATA("Val",$E$2,"Customer","A","Item","c"),GETPIVOTDATA("Val",$E$2,"Customer","A","Item","d")),IF(E4="C",MAX(GETPIVOTDATA("Val",$E$2,"Customer","C","Item","a"),GETPIVOTDATA("Val",$E$2,"Customer","C","Item","b"),GETPIVOTDATA("Val",$E$2,"Customer","C","Item","c"),GETPIVOTDATA("Val",$E$2,"Customer","C","Item","d")),""))

Note that it is hard coded for A and C being your top customers and only caters for the four Items you show. Also it returns 5 and 7 rather than ItemD and ItemC, though I think it could be adjusted for that if required.

I have used lower case to differentiate Items from Customers.

Comment: Thank you @pnuts for your help. The solution that ended up working was here [http://superuser.com/questions/522465/find-matching-value-in-a-row-and-return-column-name], combined with vlookup.